# How to get dates which are between last monday till current day?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am having dates in my database.

My database is in MySQL.

I want to fetch dates from my database which provides me dates from last monday till current day.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first have to work out how many days ago last monday was, using the `DAYOFWEEK` function, then subtract that from the current date -

```
SELECT * from table
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL MOD(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-2,7) DAY)
AND   date <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL MOD(7 - (DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) - 1), 7) DAY)
```

I'm not 100% sure about the +/- numbers here, you should be able to work it out from this though

EDIT: If this will only ever be run on the sunday at the end of the period, there is a much simpler version -

```
SELECT * from table
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 DAY)
AND   date <= CURDATE()
```

Comment: @tobyodavies: Thanks for your help. What could be done if I want to fetch data from last monday to this sunday?

Comment: it is basically the same process, but it'll be `<=` and `date_add(...,7 - MOD(DAYOFWEEK(...)-1,7) ...`

Comment: Hey didnt exactly get it. It would be really great if you could edit your answer and put it there. Also I am not clear where did the CURDATE() go in this case? Sorry I am a complete newbie into this MySQL.

Comment: edited, it needs testing though, i'm not 100% sure on if you need to subtract 1 there, I don't have a mysql install on this machine to test it...

Comment: Ok Thanks I will try out that and get back to you. :)

Comment: Hey actually I want the dates considering that today is Sunday and I want all the dates from last monday itself.

Comment: if it will always be run on the same day of the week then you can simplify it a lot... Is that what you mean - that this code will only ever be run on a sunday?

Comment: Yeah it would always be run on sunday and it would take all the data which has dates from last monday to that particular day(that would be sunday) What can be done in that case?

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
select * from table
WHERE date >date_sub(curdate(), interval WEEKDAY(curdate()) day) ;
```

Comment: Best answer to me. I had to take a moment to understand why this works but it works pretty good

Answer (score -1):

You could always use the between function in your queries...

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE order_date between to_date ('2003/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
AND to_date ('2003/12/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/between.php

Comment: Thanks for the input but this wont be applicable in my case as my dates are not fixed. I just want to fetch dates from last monday to current day. I dont know what was the date on last monday. This is not a one time process. All the dates are to be fetched once every week so I can pass the dates statically. What can be done?