# Get entries from current week?

Tags: php, mysql

Right now i have a question that gets the entries from the last 7 days

```
 AND  entries.created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) GROUP BY entries.id ORDER BY count DESC"
```

But i would like it to be current week instead, so it resets every monday.

How do I formulate a question like that?

Comment: You can the DAYOFWEEK function on the current date to calculate the interval needed to find the preceding Monday; though you will probably want to use `CURDATE()` instead of `NOW()` in the `DATE_SUB` part of the calculation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get dates which are between last monday till current day?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537112/how-to-get-dates-which-are-between-last-monday-till-current-day)

Answer (score 0):

First you can get the time for the current monday in your programming language. For example in php

```
$start = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last monday'));
```

Then you can inject the value in the sql like that:
entries.created > ${start} // 2016-11-14 for example.

Comment: AND entries.created > $start GROUP BY entries.id ORDER BY count DESC dont seam to work?

Comment: Did you try AND entries.created >= '2016-11-14' GROUP BY entries.id ORDER BY count DESC

Answer (score 0):

To do this purely in MySQL you need a way to obtain the first day of the week from any particular `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` value. Think of it as a truncate-to-last-Sunday or truncate-to-last-Monday function.

truncate-to-last-Sunday looks like this:

```
   FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -MOD(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -1, 7))
```

truncate-to-last-Monday looks like this (note **-2**)

```
   FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -MOD(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -2, 7))
```

(Choose Sunday or Monday based on your locality's business rule about which day of the week is considered the first day.)

Then, your `WHERE` clause will contain something like this:

```
AND entries.created >= FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -MOD(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -1, 7))
```

One wishes MySQL had a `TRUNCATE_TO_WEEK(datestamp,locality)` function. But it doesn't.

If you're trying to summarize your table by calendar week, you need something like this.

```
  SELECT 
     FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(entries.created) -MOD(TO_DAYS(entries.created) -1, 7)) week_begins,
     COUNT(*) entries_count
  FROM
     entries
  GROUP BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(entries.created) -MOD(TO_DAYS(entries.created) -1, 7))
  ORDER BY 1
```

Here's a more comprehensive explanation of this point, including some convenient stored functions.

http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/